# Equal condition for list of objects in java

Tags: java, java-8

I'm looking for the solution to iterate the list and check for some condition in java for list of objects.

Note: I mentioned it as table because we are fetching the records from database through java and iterating to check the condition.

For example the list contains below records with below code,

```
Id     name
1      Tom
2      Jack
3      Tom

public class ListObjects {
     private boolean checkEqual(List<Client> clientList){
         for(Client clientName : clientList) {
             if(clientName.equals("Tom") && clientName.equals("Jack")){
                 System.out.println("Validation success");
             }
         }
     }
}
```

How to check the name condition for list of objects in java for above code.

TIA.,

Comment: What have you tried yourself to solve the issue?

Comment: It's tagged with the `database` flag, so I guess a better approach would be to the check with sql (RDBMS only though). Also I don't get if you need to know if there are any duplicates or you need the indices or what?

Comment: We tagged it as database because I have mentioned the database records. I am looking for the solution to check through java

Comment: so you want to check object1.name == object3.name?

Comment: @Alan better check `object1.name.equals(object3.name)`...

Comment: right, because they are strings. but i wasnt really presenting a solution there, just asking what OP is trying to ask

Comment: @DIVA please add your java attempt...

Comment: @DIVA it's still unclear what is the aim of the comparison. Please explain or give an example of what you expect as output.

Comment: In Java, there is no notion of “record” or “table”. You have to define the prerequisites in terms of classes and objects.

Comment: @Alan - I have reedited my question as per the requirement.

Comment: @DIVA can you post a code example, of where you need to compare those entries?

Comment: @Alan Please see my above reedited question

Comment: alright thanks, see if my answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your object you can do:

```
public class MyObject{
    //your classes code here

    public boolean equals(MyObject toCompare){
        return this.name.equals(toCompare.name);
    }
}
```

And in your other class where you need to check those entries:

```
if(object1.equals(object2)){
    //whatever you want to do if they are equal
}
```

EDIT:

in your example code you loop through all clients inside your list and on every client you check if his name is tom and jack. But this doesnt make sense, as a client cant be tom AND jack at the same time. I think what you were trying to do was:

```
public class ListObjects {
     private boolean checkEqual(List<Client> clientList){
         for(Client clientName : clientList) {
             if(clientName.name.equals("Tom") || clientName.name.equals("Jack")){
                 System.out.println("Validation success");
             }
         }
     }
}
```

additionally you need to do clientName.name to get access to the clientname. in your for loop clientName is just a full client

Another Edit:

if you use the equals method above, you can do

```
private boolean checkEqual(List<Client> clientList){
     return clientList.contains("Tom") || clientList.contains("Jack");
}
```

and it will be true if tom or jack are in the list

Comment: Yes. This is my requirement how to do it in better approach for checking the condition for list of objects.

Comment: check edit, there is a better approach

Comment: Thanks Alan for your suggestion.